# duplicate symbols in AdMob

Tags: objective-c, ios6, admob

When archiving, such en error occurs:

```
Projects/Dossier/MultiDocument/Helpers/GAD/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
    duplicate symbol _tohex in:
        /Users/shmidt/Documents/App Development/Xcode Projects/Dossier/MultiDocument/Helpers/GAD/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(rc4.o)
        /Users/shmidt/Documents/App Development/Xcode Projects/Dossier/MultiDocument/Helpers/GAD/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
    ld: 64 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're using the Admob v6.2 library make sure you're NOT using the `-all_load` linker flag, use the `-ObjC` linker flag instead.

Comment: Thanks friend, it also solved my problem. I used sharekit where -all_load is used, now I removed and don't face this problem.

Comment: I have been facing the same problem with the latest admob SDK. After removing the -all_load it's gone. But, I was wondering that they specifically asked to put that flag in the linker flags property

Comment: Note: had to close XCode and open the project again for the build to finally work on XCode 5.0. "Clean" project didn't work.

Comment: @rajPara i facing this problem in cocoa2d Game with the latest admob SDK , now i removed the -all_load  the error is solved but app is crashed in the starting , any idea , i am using the latest admob SDK

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find any "-all_load" params but also show this error.

you must goto the "project.xcodeproj" and replace "-all_load" with "-ObjC" in "project.pbxproj"

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem within a Unity game and I had added IronSource Mediation Adapters, if it's your case here's the solution I found:
You should use the pods. I guess you are aware of it, but in case you don't know it, it's something like google play services in the Apple products, designed for taking care of the external packages and libraries to include in the project.
When you manually add the frameworks into the project it conflicts with other codes of the same package that might already be in the project. In my case solution was removing the "GoogleUtilities" and "nanopb" from Google's Admob frameworks and also the "FBCoreKit" from the Facebook ads frameworks(which had conflicts) and added the following code to a dependencies file in the Unity:

```
<iosPods>
        `enter code here`<iosPod name="FBAudienceNetwork" version="5.6.0" />
        `enter code here`<iosPod name="Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK" version="7.50.0" />
</iosPods>
```

This code lets pods take care of the conflicting libraries and removes the duplicate symbols that didn't permit the build to succeed.