# Apple Mach-O Linker error Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, error-handling

I try to build my app for archiving in my iPhone and iPad app, but I get this error... This started to happen since I added AdMob. I don't know what is wrong. I hate those Mach-O Linker errors....

```
Ld "build/Högskoleprovet - Matematik.build/Release-iphoneos/Högskoleprovet - Matematik.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/HP-Matte" normal armv7s
cd "/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang - arch armv7s -isysroot               /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk "-L/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/build/Release-iphoneos" "-L/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite" "-F/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/build/Release-iphoneos" -filelist "/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/build/Högskoleprovet - Matematik.build/Release-iphoneos/Högskoleprovet - Matematik.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/HP-Matte.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -all_load -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -framework MessageUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AudioToolbox -framework AdSupport -framework StoreKit -framework iAd -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lGoogleAdMobAds -o "/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/build/Högskoleprovet - Matematik.build/Release-iphoneos/Högskoleprovet - Matematik.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/HP-Matte"

        /Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
    duplicate symbol _CFStringToCString in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _CheckJailBreakStatus in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _CompareByAddress in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _ComputeDigest in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _CopyParentMethodFromCallStack in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _CopySystemInformation in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _DoBitSlicer in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _FindSwizzling in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GatherSignals in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetAdVisibility in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetAppUsageTime in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetClassMethod in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetDeviceBatteryLevel in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetDeviceBatteryState in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetDeviceID in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetDeviceOrientation in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetEncryptedData in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetInstanceMethod in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetIntFromDictionary in:
 /Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetNetworkType in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetOverlap in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetStackTrace in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetStrFromDictionary in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _GetViewInfo in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _InitGlobalData in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _InitNotifications in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _IsClassMethodAvailable in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _IsDeviceOrientationEnabled in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _IsInstanceMethodAvailable in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _IsPropertyAvailable in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
duplicate symbol _MD5 in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(md5.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _MD5_final in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(md5.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _MD5_init in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(md5.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _MD5_update in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(md5.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _MethodAddress in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
  duplicate symbol _ObfuscateBinaryValue in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _SetBatteryMonitoringStatus in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _SimpleWireFormatFreeBuffer in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(SimpleWireFormat.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _SimpleWireFormatMakeBuffer in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(SimpleWireFormat.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _SimpleWireFormatWriteInt64 in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(SimpleWireFormat.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _SimpleWireFormatWriteRaw in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(SimpleWireFormat.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _SimpleWireFormatWriteString in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(SimpleWireFormat.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _SimpleWireFormatWriteTag in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(SimpleWireFormat.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _SimpleWireFormatWriteVarint32 in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(SimpleWireFormat.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _SimpleWireFormatWriteVarint64 in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(SimpleWireFormat.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _do_rc4 in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(rc4.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _freeDecodedString in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _gad_bs in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(des_e.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _gad_gig in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _gad_gmcs in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _gad_gmrs in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _gad_htg in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGesture.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _gethex in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(rc4.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _htoa in:
 /Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(rc4.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _set_crypt_key in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(rc4.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 duplicate symbol _tohex in:
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(rc4.o)
/Högskoleprovet - Matematik iPad Lite/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
 ld: 64 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What could be wrong? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

/A noob

Comment: I don't have Xcode in front of me, but try this. Go to Targets, then click on the fourth tab on the top. Expand each of the four sections until you find the section with all of your project's .m files inside. Are the files for Admob in there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [duplicate symbols in AdMob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727575/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7s)

Comment: To save a click: get rid of the `-all_load` linker flag.

Comment: no the AdMob files are not in there, Jack!

When I remove the -all_load, the app crashes when I press a certain button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the -ObjC in other linker flag in build setting.

Answer (score 3):

Just go the target, then build settings , then in the other linker flags option, remove the **-all_load** flag. This will help you resolve the problem.