# Apple Mach-O Linker (ID) Error _compress and linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker-errors, mach-o

I have been working on an app to upload photo images from an iPhone to a web server for internship, but every time I try to run the app, I get a Mach-O Linker Error.
I have tried everything I found on this site (recreating the app, add libz.dylib, add QuartzCore.Framework), but the errors still remain.
Anyone know what's wrong with the code?

Error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:<br>
"_compress", referenced from:<br>
 -[Uploader(Private) compress:] in AppDelegate.o<br>
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64<br>
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)<br>
```

---

```
Ld /Users/AppleStoreStaples/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoUploader-bafqzogdtrxrvdgesppeismhxrkf/Build/Products/Debug/PhotoUploader.app/Contents/MacOS/PhotoUploader normal x86_64
cd /Users/AppleStoreStaples/Documents/Projects/PhotoUploader
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/AppleStoreStaples/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoUploader-bafqzogdtrxrvdgesppeismhxrkf/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/AppleStoreStaples/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoUploader-bafqzogdtrxrvdgesppeismhxrkf/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/AppleStoreStaples/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoUploader-bafqzogdtrxrvdgesppeismhxrkf/Build/Intermediates/PhotoUploader.build/Debug/PhotoUploader.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PhotoUploader.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -fobjc-link-runtime -framework QuartzCore -framework Cocoa -o /Users/AppleStoreStaples/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoUploader-bafqzogdtrxrvdgesppeismhxrkf/Build/Products/Debug/PhotoUploader.app/Contents/MacOS/PhotoUploader
```

Comment: What is `compress()`?  It's not a standard API call AFAIK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple Mach-O Linker error Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126809/apple-mach-o-linker-error-xcode)

Comment: you are building for iPhone? Why do you have setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AppDelegate` file includes a category called `Uploader (Private)`. It defines a method called `compress:`, which uses a function called `compress()`. You haven't linked whatever implements the `compress()` function into the app binary.