# duplicate symbol _MD5 in libcrypto and libGoogleAdMobAds

Tags: ios, linker, compiler-errors

My project when compile to armv7 structure has this error:

```
duplicate symbol _MD5 in:
    /Users/User1/Documents/codes/ProgramList1/libraries/armv7/lib/libcrypto.a(md5_one.o)
    /Users/User1/Documents/codes/ProgramList1/ProgramList1/ADs/AdsMoGoLib/AdNetworkLibs/AdMob_SDK_621/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I googled this problem, and I read that someone suggests to combine the two libs into one to get rid of the duplicate symbol, like this:

```
> lipo libGoogleAdMobAds.a -thin armv7 -output libGoogleAdMobAds-armv7.a
> mkdir armv7
> cd armv7/
> ar -x ../libGoogleAdMobAds-armv7.a 
> ar -x ../libcrypto.a 
> libtool -static -o ../libcrypto-googlead-armv7.a *.o
```

At last, I go back to project, remove the libGoogleAdMobAds.a and libcrypto.a from link flags and add the new combined lib to project.

But I still get the same error:

```
duplicate symbol _MD5 in:
    /Users/User1/Documents/codes/ProgramList1/libraries/armv7/lib/libGoogleAdMobAds-armv7.a(md5_one.o)
    /Users/User1/Documents/codes/ProgramList1/ProgramList1/ADs/AdsMoGoLib/AdNetworkLibs/libGoogleAdMobAds-armv7.a(GADGestureCFiles.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As you can see, there's duplicate symbol in the same lib. What should I do now?

Comment: have you set the all_load flag in the Other Linker Flags of your Project/Target build settings?

Comment: Yes, my Other Linker Flags is like this: -all_load -ObjC -lxml2 -levent -lssl -lcurl -l....

Comment: BTW, this error only occurs when built for iOS(armv7), when built for simulator(i386), the project is build successfully.

Comment: Thanks calvinBhai, after remove all_load from link flags, it works now. I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12737840/739063

Comment: checkout the link I have posted in the answer. you'll better understand as to why you were having this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reposting comment for answer

"have you set the all_load flag in the Other Linker Flags of your Project/Target build settings?"

here is a excellent detailed explanation about what all_load does:

[Why is -force_load no longer required for my three20 dependencies in XCode 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942616/why-is-force-load-no-longer-required-for-my-three20-dependencies-in-xcode-4-2/7942924#7942924)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `-all_load` in your build settings linker flag.

It is safe to remove, even if some libraries asked you to add that.